# HTAccess rewrite dynamic page url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

thanks for your help in advance

Basically i have made a dynamic url website `http://planet-dj-surrey.com/`

I cant seem to figure out the code for the htaccess file to redirect a dynamic page and make it cleaner.

for example i want `http://planet-dj-surrey.com/index.php?page=designprocess`
to be changed to

```
http://planet-dj-surrey.com/designprocess/
```

currently i have this but it does not seem to be working,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/dropdownchoice/$   index.php?page=dropdownchoice  [NC]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lose the leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=$1  [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ post.php?post_name=$1&post_id=$2 [L]
```