# Hide dynamic page "movie.php?id=10" from my PHP website's URLs and replace spaces with hyphens

Tags: php

My website's URLs are as:
"/movie.php?id=10 Rangoon (2017)"

Spaces are converted to %20 by web browser.

But I want the simple URL like this:
"/Rangoon-(2017)"

How Can I do that?

My website is developed in PHP and all data of my website is placed on MySql Database and "movie.php" page retrieves the data from MySql Database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTAccess rewrite dynamic page url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662770/htaccess-rewrite-dynamic-page-url)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I don't think so, the topic you linked is easier to manage than this one.

Comment: @Waqas your code?

Comment: @MarcBrillault its all the same it's all about you writing the rules

Comment: On the topic you linked, there is an easy link between the title and the page to display. In this case, @Waqas would have to add a step to link the title and the id.

Comment: @JoseMarques, my website's URLs are dynamically generating from custom made php sitemap builder.

Comment: here is the code

Comment: $name = $xml -> createElement("loc","http://statusweb.org/movie.php?id=".$row['movie_id'].(" ").$row['movie_name']);

Comment: @Waqas u need to add the code with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not a simple one, you'll have to make many updates :

1. generate an url for each of you movie pages (By the way, don't use parenthesis in an url, in your example the url should be something like `rangoon-2017`). You may use my method
   [seoUrl](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/helpers/blob/master/src/seo.php)
2. store this url somewhere in your database
3. Decide on an url scheme, like `movie/title-of-your-movie`
4. When displaying a link, display the url scheme
5. create an .htaccess file which rewrites `movie/whatever` to `movie.php?url=whatever`
6. On movie.php, retrieve your movie information from the url and not the id

Additional thoughts :

- you'll have to make sure each movie has an unique url. Adding the year is a good idea, since I doubt two movies will have the exact same title and year.
- also, make sure your urls are unique in the database (And indexed, since you'll search from them)
- why the prefix `movie/` on the url ? Simply because if you don't create it, you'll find more difficult to redirect other type of pages to the correct file.

Comment: Can you please give me the example that how to include these rules on my code?

Comment: I'm not going to develop this myself : where are you stuck ?

Comment: Actually I am thinking that which method will be best for my website from those you have suggested. But still cat't make decision.

Comment: These are not a list of suggested methods, but a step-by-step howto : you'll have to follow __all__ of these steps in order to make it work.

Comment: Okay,
kindly give me this example by code so that I can easily understand the logic.

Comment: As I told you before; I won't. Just try and tell me where you are stuck. I'll help then.

Comment: Okay, let me do it myself. Thank you

Comment: Hey!
I have successfully changed the "Rangoon (2017)" to "rangoon-2017" by including your seoUrl method.
But I can't remove the "movie.php?id=10" from the URL

Comment: The urls will not change automatically : your scripts will have to generate the "movie/whatever" from the database.